# How to avoid Adding runat="server" destroying my server tags <%...%>

Tags: asp.net, runatserver, server-tags

#### Adding runat="server" is not rendering my server tags <%...%>

I have a masterpage with a few  <li> for menu and since I have to set class=selected for the current page, I am using a little server tag to find the url and assign the particular class.

I have total of 10 <li> and not all menu is available to all types of user, I need to toggle few of the <li> if the user is not admin, so I have runat="server" added to them so I can set their visible=false through c#

Here is how it is at a glance:

```
<li runat="server" id="liBlog" class='<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/Blog") ? "selected" : "" %>'><a href="/Blog">Group Blog</a></li>
<li runat="server" id="liPoll" class='<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/Poll") ? "selected" : "" %>'><a href="/Poll">Poll</a></li>
<li id="liInvite" class='<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/Invite") ? "selected" : "" %>'><a href="/Invite">Invite</a></li>
<li id="liFavourite" class='<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/Favourite") ? "selected" : "" %>'><a href="/Favourite">My Favourites</a></li>
```

The <li> without runat="server" works fine, when on correct page the source code shows class="selected" or class="" as appropriate, the other <li> used to work fine too, until I decided to add the runat="server".

Once I added that runat="server", the whole block of class="" is being sent out to the html page, its not processing the server tags at all! I right click on the html and look at the source, it's being rendered as:

```
<li id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_liBlog" class="&lt;%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith(&quot;/Blog&quot;) ? &quot;selected&quot; : &quot;&quot; %&gt;"><a href="/Blog">Group Blog</a></li>
```

It's pouring out my server tags into the source code!

Why is this behaviour seen? How can I avoid it?

I looked up a lot of similar threads in here and there was nearly nothing in google, so made this, I dont think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Something upcoming you may be interested in: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: thanks very much @Nick Craver, I am reading through all the articles on the page and see what helps! thanks!

Comment: interesting.. but but i cannot use its yet! shame!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `<%= %>` syntax inside the properties of tags that have the `runat="server"` attribute on them.

You either need to:

- Set the properties via your code-behind
- Create an [Expression Builder](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders.html) (and [part 2](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders-2--.html) and [part 3](http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2009/05/aspnet-expression-builders-3--.html)) and use the `<%$ %>` syntax (note: these are links to stuff I wrote on *my* blog, so, beware the self link =)

Comment: Where did you hear about not being able to use them? IIRC (not doing web stuff recently) I did it all the time!

Comment: thanks, I am reading up on them, will let you know how it goes.. thanks!

Comment: Holy Batman!  For some reason I thought it worked. Testing just gave me: Parser Error Message: `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs`.

Comment: @leppie - "Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs." when I tried to add one, just to check my own sanity! =)

Comment: parse error is saying that you cannot user servertags <% %> ?
i think you need to add <%= %> or <%# %> depending on normal or databinding tags that you are adding..

Comment: Hi I took your advice and converted class code to c# by a bunch of if else loops like 
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/Blog"))
                liBlog.Attributes["class"] = "selected";

thanks for the advice though, else I would have wasted several more minutes trying to work out (read as clueless-ly wondering) what to do

Answer (score 0):

for your requirement you can also use ASP.NET menu and XmlSiteMap to do the same thing.