# ASP C# - How to disable a button (that runs on server) from a client?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.net with C# and there's this button that I want it to be disabled according to a boolean I keep.

This works:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" <%=ConfigurationHandler.IsImpersonate ? "disabled" : "" %>Click Me!</button>
```

This doesn't:

```
<button runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="ui_click_me" <%=ConfigurationHandler.IsImpersonate ? "disabled" : "" %>>Click Me!</button>
```

The error I get is:

> Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

What is the best way to disable the button? (according to the boolean).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate. [How to avoid Adding runat=“server” destroying my server tags <%…%>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3371049/1260204)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom Expression builder for your scenario.

Following are built in expression builders in .net.

- Resources
- ConnectionStrings
- AppSettings

Please follow the instructions explained [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx/)

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx/

Comment: Hey, i've checked out this solution and it works. So thanks.But. it's a bit 'dirty' solution and i'd like to keep my code as "clean" as i can. Currently i'm using a temporary solution that i'm disabling the button from the HtmlControl rather than from the Html/Asp.